# Xcode - Long startup / non-responsive during initial startup

Tags: xcode

If I already have Xcode open and I close the current project and then open any project, even a different one, it takes less than a minute
to load the project and become available. If I exit Xcode completely, however, and then try to open any project it takes about 10-15 minutes to finish loading and become available.

During this time I see that Xcode takes 99% of CPU cycles in the Activity Monitor and showing is marked as "Not Responding."

Is there anything that I can do to speed this up or resolve it?

Comment: I am in trouble please help me ASAP.

Comment: This isn't a programming question. This sounds like a computer/software issue. Try asking on apple.stackexchange.com

Comment: Welcome to SO!  I've reworded your question a bit and made some changes to the grammar to make it more digestible.  This may lead to you receiving more responses to the question.

Comment: try removing all your derived data

Comment: Thanks a lot for replied @ David and Paul, I already removed all my derived data from my system, but problem did not solve @Paul. Please note that My xcode was working fine, But after add/install provision/developer profile in my xcode this prblem( long startup / non-responsive during initial startup) coming in xcode. Please let me know if you you know other method to solve this problem ASAP. I will thankful to you.